# State of RefreshView is invoking RefreshCommand in .NET MAUI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I have a `CollectionView` in my .NET MAUI app and I placed it inside a `RefreshView`. When I call my API to populate this `CollectionView`, I cache the data so that I don't have to keep making API calls everytime the user hits this page.

In order to streamline my code, I created a `private` method in my view model that calls my API. The view model looks like this:

```
public partial MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyData { get; } = new();

   [RelayCommand]
   async Task RefreshData()
   {
      IsBusy = true;

      await GetData(true);

      IsBusy = false;
   }

   private async Task GetData(bool shouldGetFreshData)
   {
       // Makes API call to get data, then assigns it to MyData collection
   }

   public async void Init()
   {
       IsBusy = true;

       await GetData(false);
 
       IsBusy = false;
   }
}
```

The XAML for the page looks like this:

```
<RefreshView
   IsRefreshing={Binding IsBusy}
   Command={Binding RefreshDataCommand}>
   <CollectionView>
   ...
   </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

I also wired the page to use the `MyViewModel` as its view model AND `OnAppearing()`, I call the `Init()` method of the view model.

Here's what I was expecting which is NOT what's happening:

I thought, the `Init()` would get called first which then calls the `GetData()` method with `false` input parameter. This way, I could use the cached data. And whenever, the user refreshes the `CollectionView` by pulling it down, the `RefreshData()` method would be called with `true` as the input parameter which would force the code to make an API call.

Instead of what I was expecting, here's what's happening:

1. The `Init()` method gets called first and as a result, the line with `IsBusy = true` executes.
2. This then ends up invoking the `RefreshData()` method
3. Then the `await GetData(false)` in `Init()` method executes
4. Then the `await GetData(true)` in `RefreshData()` method executes

As a result of all this, the `GetData()` method gets called twice.

I think, what's triggering this is the `IsBusy`. I thought `IsBusy` would only serve as an indicator but not necessarily invoke the `RefreshData()` method which is bound to the `Command` of my `RefreshView`.

Is this normal behavior or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, this is "normal" behavior because I'm manually setting `IsBusy` to `true`. I decided to leave this question here because this may be a pitfall that affects others.

Here's the actual section in documentation that states this:
[image]

And here's the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview

So, all I had to do is remove the `IsBusy = true` in `Init()` method.

Comment: FWIW, a common pattern for methods/commands attached to UI elements (in any language or platform), is to have a bool flag (e.g. `syncing`). If want commands/UI-event-handlers to ignore programmatic changes to values, set that to true before altering value, then false afterwards. Wrapping all that in a try-catch is recommended, so can't accidentally leave in a non-responsive state. Command method would start with `if (syncing) return;`.  Code that modifies state does `try { vm.syncing = true; IsBusy = true; } finally { vm.syncing = false; }`. Won't help if refresh actually runs slightly later.